# docker-compose still using override file with the -f option

Tags: docker-compose

Everything thing I can find indicates that if I use the -f option to reference a `yml` file, it won't override the values with the override file... but this is not happening in my case. The command I'm running is:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml build`

However I get an error that it can't find a `.env` file that is specified in my `docker-compose.override.yml` file.

I renamed the override file and everything worked fine. Why is it still merging with my override file?

Comment: For clarification, the sentence "I renamed the override file and everything worked fine.", should say "I renamed the override file to `docker-compose.debug.yml` and now everything works - as you would expect. However, I'm still not sure why the override file was being picked up, as per the official docs, using the -f flag should prevent the override file from being used."

Comment: To be sure we're not dealing with a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/591014) here could you add the specific error message you are getting about the `.env` file and also the relevant parts from your `docker-compose.yml` files? Maybe even provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Compose copies configurations from the original service over to the local one. If a configuration option is defined in both the original service and the local service, the local value replaces or extends the original value.

- For single-value options like `image`, `command` or `mem_limit`, the new value replaces the old value.
- For the multi-value options `ports`, `expose`, `external_links`, `dns`,
  `dns_search`, and `tmpfs`, Compose concatenates both sets of values:
- In the case of `environment`, `labels`, `volumes`, and `devices`, Compose **merges** entries together with locally-defined values taking precedence.

Refer Docs Here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration

You can read generated config like below, once its fine start containers, here is demonstration on merge/override demo

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml  -f docker-compose.override.yml config
```

**Sample files**

```
$ pwd
/tmp/merge-demo

$ ls *.yml
docker-compose.override.example.yml  docker-compose.yml
```

**Content of `docker-compose.yml`**

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      RAILS_ENV: test
    ports:
     - 80:80
    logging:
      options:
        max-file: '5'
        max-size: 1m
```

**Content of `docker-compose.override.example.yml`**

```
$ cat docker-compose.override.example.yml 
services:
  app:
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - coverage:/app/coverage
      - log:/app/log
      - bundle-config:/app/spec/gemfiles/.bundle
      - dummy-log:/app/spec/dummy/log
      - dummy-tmp:/app/spec/dummy/tmp

volumes:
  coverage: {}
  log: {}
  bundle-config: {}
  dummy-log: {}
  dummy-tmp: {}
```

**Contents after merging:**

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml  -f docker-compose.override.example.yml config
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: /tmp/merge-demo
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      RAILS_ENV: test
    logging:
      options:
        max-file: '5'
        max-size: 1m
    ports:
    - published: 80
      target: 80
    - published: 8080
      target: 8080
    volumes:
    - /tmp/merge-demo:/app:rw
    - coverage:/app/coverage:rw
    - log:/app/log:rw
    - dummy-log:/app/spec/dummy/log:rw
    - dummy-tmp:/app/spec/dummy/tmp:rw
    - bundle-config:/app/spec/gemfiles/.bundle:rw
version: '3.9'
volumes:
  bundle-config: {}
  coverage: {}
  dummy-log: {}
  dummy-tmp: {}
  log: {}
```

Comment: Hmmm, if you look at my example, I am specifying 2 yml files, and neither is the override file, therefore the override file should not be getting merged according to the docs.

Comment: @raydenl I think still you didn't understand the behaviour kindly read once again

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to provide an answer. I understood, I just think in the context I am referring too, your answer is wrong. If you look at the same document link you provided me, further up it exactly provides my example. Please re-read the document you provided me around the use of specific `override` files, i.e. "This deploys all three services using the configuration in docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.prod.yml (but not the dev configuration in docker-compose.override.yml)."

Comment: @raydenl: See it depends on value see my listed points, above I just tried to give example, infact in your post you haven't provided sample of your docker-compose even how do you expect others to imagine, for example whats the meaning of "I renamed the override file and everything worked fine. Why is it still merging with my override file?", it was just a demonstration on how values will interpreted by docker-compose in different context.

Comment: Fair enough. I have clarified it for you :)